# Is this the best way to handle storage of uploaded files in Django?

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I'm not sure if I should use something like `fs.save()` or another method, such as chunking, to handle file uploads in Django. So far this is my method:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(uploaded_file):
    filename = uploaded_file.name
    filepath = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename)
    with open(uploaded_file.name, 'wb') as destination:
        for chunk in uploaded_file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
        return filepath

@csrf_protect
def transcribeSubmit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('valid')
            uploaded_file = handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
```

The purpose of this view is to handle video and audio uploads if this is relevant. I haven't been able to find any good and simple documentation on this.